# How mimic delete specific row in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a list of things in a table view.

When a user tap a row, I increase score. I wish provide a way to clear the score for that row.

My first try is put the table in edit mode, show the delete button to that row and proceed. However, all the other rows get blocked and can't tap again the score or tap in the disclosure button.

So, obviously this is not the way. But then I don't see what to do. Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried to "exit" the row after you delete the row?

Comment: What I learned recently, (which might merit a comment), is that the default delete button is wired into the table's behavior. So if you want to repurpose it to delete the contents of the cell, that is okay, but you do need to override, otherwise using the button will trigger a lot of internal table activity. This was never clearly explained in the current nor legacy docs.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a button to clear the row’s score as a subview of your table cell. I suppose you’d have to put it on the left side, though, since the disclosure button is on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Probably... Once you finish updating the table, you need to take the table back out of edit mode.